# Mongodb Embedding structure and search

Tags: mongodb

If I have a collection: Visitor and I would like to embed an array of Visits in it, then it will look something like this:

```
Visitor1
->Visit 1
->Visit 2

Visitor2
->Visit 1
->Visit 2
```

- Is this a good structure ?
- When I will have millions of documents, I will have to first look for the visitor then add a visit, is this structure efficient ?
- How do I display all visits for all visitors ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it can be efficient depending on what you have to do more often. The structure in and by itself is fine. You always getting all visits for a single visitor for "free" when you query a visitor is the biggest advantage so you get all visits for a single visitor pretty easy. It also means you don't need a visits collection which cleans up your schema.

Here are example implementations to the operations you require :

**Adding a visit :**

`db.visitors.update({_id:<visitorId>}, {$push:{visits:<newVisit>}})`

**Removing a visit :**

`db.visitors.update({_id:<visitorId>}, {$pull:{visits:{visitId:<visitId>}})`

If you meant displaying all visits of all visitors combined there's no direct way to do so currently. You can do so with either a distinct operation and some application logic to unwrap the individual arrays or use m/r. In 2.2. there will be an aggregation framework which can do that just fine.

There are some things to consider though :

- Documents have a 16mb limit. If you can have enough visits to reach this limitation then you require a seperate visit collection.
- Querying for some visits of a specific visitor is not possible. You always query top level documents so if a user has 14,000 visits and you only need a specific few you'll have to retrieve the entire document. For paging some of this can be handled by using $slice.
- Modifying multiple visits for a single visitor with one update can be a tricky without a seperate visits collection. You can only address one array element per update through the positional operator $.

Hope that helps.